# DiscordPy Extension 'cogs.economy' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, discord.py

I get the following error when i run my bot.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.economy' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

I have the extension economy.py in the folder cogs. economy.py:

```
from discord.ext import commands


class Economy(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author != self.client.user:
            await message.channel.send("hello")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Economy(client))
```

and my client.py has:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True


prefix = "?"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.load_extension('hello')
    await client.load_extension('cogs.economy')
    print("Bot is ready")

client.run(token=token)
```

I have tried async-await for the setup but i still cant around this. This is my first time coding a bot. The 'hello' has just a command in it, and it works just fine. I have no idea how there is a NoneType object here.

Thanks.

Edit: Full Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Documents\PythonProjects\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 946, in _load_from_module_spec
await setup(self)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Documents\PythonProjects\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Documents\PythonProjects\DiscordBot\exp_bot.py", line 51, in on_ready
await client.load_extension('cogs.economy')
File "D:\Documents\PythonProjects\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
File "D:\Documents\PythonProjects\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 951, in _load_from_module_spec
raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.economy' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show FULL error message but it shows problem with `await setup(self)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 946, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/furas/main.py", line 18, in on_ready
    await client.load_extension('cogs.economy')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 951, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.economy' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

and it may suggest that `setup()` has to use `async`.

When I use `async def setup(client)` then I gets different error

```
/home/furas/cogs/economy.py:19: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  client.add_cog(Economy(client))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

which may suggest that `add_cog()` has to use `await`

---

Code works for me when I add `async` and `await`.

```
async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Economy(client))
```

---

**BTW:**

Documentation for [load_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/extensions.html) also shows `async def setup()`

Comment: Hey thanks! it worked. I saw the documentation, but it only had a command in it. Thought it was different cogs with classes. And i was doing this watching a tutorial on youtube. The guy used `def setup` only and it worked for him.

Comment: how old is this tutorial? Maybe they changed something in `discord` and now `setup` needs `async`?

Comment: nearly a year old. Yeah probably. There is always something changing lol!